# For Loop within While Infinite Loop Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

Can someone please have a look at the below code. It goes in an infinite loop. Please help!

```
while (findelement("//*[starts-with(@class,'paging-next')]")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Hotel_Name.size(); i++) {
            String h = Hotel_Name.get(i).getAttribute("title");
            String s = Star_Rating.get(i).getAttribute("class");
            System.out.println(h + "|" + s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does the function "findelement" do?

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming findelement [this](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) (although it most likely isn't since if it was your code wouldn't compile in this state). You need to do something with your while loop, at the moment it simply finds an element, but has no boolean value to work with. So you are returned a webelement and loop forever. Try this instead:

```
while (findelement("//*[starts-with(@class,'paging-next')]").isDisplayed()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Hotel_Name.size(); i++) {
        String h = Hotel_Name.get(i).getAttribute("title");
        String s = Star_Rating.get(i).getAttribute("class");
        System.out.println(h + "|" + s);
    }
}
```

This way you will only loop while that element is displayed, you could also specify to loop while it is enabled or selected. The idea is you only want this to run when these conditions are true, and not when they are false.

Comment: If it were that findElement then the code wouldn't compile. I'm pretty sure we're missing some code here....